# LocalStorage - проверка ключей и значения

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Хотел бы узнать, можно ли как то, через цикл `for` проверять ключ `localStorage.getItem(...)` и значения
я решил попробовать сделать возврат текста, но когда я попытался сделать вывод этого самого ключа и его
значения, то не смог понять как проверять их, к примеру
`for(let i = 0; i < ключ.length; i++){`
`out.innerHTML = ключ[i];`

`}`
Так же и со значением, но не понимаю как их фиксировать, то есть как мне обозначить ключ и значение переменной.
[image: Скрин]

Comment: localStorage.getItem(blablala) === string. Вам нужно масиву применить (json stringify) і потом добавлять в localStorage, а потом при получении розпаристь его через(json parse)

Comment: Не понял что ты имеешь ввиду под "(json parse)", " (json stringify)" и "localStorage.getItem(blablala) === string", я с localStorage практиковался очень мало, так что не очень понимаю, что нужно делать

Answer (score 0):

**LocalStorage** принимает только **string** значение, чтобы сохранить массив его сначала перевести в формат **JSON**, а потом можно распарсить(**JSON.parse**) и получить массив обратно. Сделал пример

```js
const arr = [];

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const one = document.querySelector('#one').value;
    const two = document.querySelector('#two').value;
    arr.push(one)
    arr.push(two)
    localStorage.setItem('arr', JSON.stringify(arr))
});

const newArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr'));

newArr.forEach((element, index) => {
    console.log(index, element)
})
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="one">
        <label for="one">ONE</label>
        <input type="text" id="two" >
        <label for="two">TWO</label>
        <button id="btn">CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может это поможет.

```
for( let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) { 
    console.log(`Local Storage key = ${localStorage.key(i)} value = ${ localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))}`);
}
```